# A few questions about Example $3.15$ from the paper $I^K\text{-}\textit{convergence}$ by Sleziak & Macaj

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, ordinals

The link to the paper [$I^K$*Convergence* by Sleziak and Macaj](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/papers/IKconv2.pdf)

> **Example $3.15:$** Let us recall that $ω_1$ denotes the first uncountable ordinal with the usual ordering. Let $X$ be the topological space on the set $ω_1 ∪ \{ω_1\}$ with the topology such that all points different from $ω_1$ are isolated and the base at the point $ω_1$ consists of all sets $U_α = \{β ∈
> X; β > α\}$ for $α < ω_1$. **Notice that if $C ⊆ ω_1$ is a set such that $ω_1 ∈ \bar C$, then $|C| = ℵ_1$**.
>
> Now let $I$ be an admissible ideal on $\mathbb N$ and let a function $f : \mathbb N → X$ be $I$-convergent to $ω_1$.
>   We will show that then there exists $M ∈ F(I)$ such that $f(x) = ω_1$ for each $x ∈ M$, that is, $f|_M$ is constant. Clearly, this implies that $f$ is $I∗$
>   -convergent.For the sake of contradiction, suppose that each set $M ∈ F(I)$ contains some point $m$ such that $f(m)\neq ω_1$. Since $f^{−1}
> (U) ∈ F(I)$, for any neighborhood $U$ of $ω_1$ in $X$ there exists $m ∈ \mathbb N$ with $f(m) ∈ U \ \{ω_1\}$. Therefore for the set $C = \{m ∈ \mathbb N; f(m)\neq ω_1\}$ we have $ω_1 ∈ f[C]$. Since $f[C] ⊆ ω_1$ and it is a countable set contained in $ω_1$, this is a contradiction.
>   Now, by choosing an ideal $I$ which does not have the additive property $AP(I, Fin)$ we obtain the desired counterexample.

$1)$**"Notice that if $C ⊆ ω_1$ is a set such that $ω_1 ∈ \bar C$, then $|C| = ℵ_1$"**: Is this another theorem or am I supposed  to derived from here?In the later case I'll really need a little hint.

$2)$ When we say $C\subset \omega_1$ we mean that $C$ is family(may be singleton even) of countable ordinals, is it$?$The space $X$ here something like $\mathbb R \bigcup \{\infty\}$ if we denoted $\mathbb R$ by $\infty$. Every member of $\mathbb R$ itself is a finite number but their *upper bound* is $\infty$ which is nothing finite.Similarly every member of $\omega_1$ is a countable ordinal but $\omega_1$ itself is not although it is the upper limit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $C\subseteq\omega_1$ is countable; then $\sup C<\omega_1$. Let $\alpha=\sup C$; then $U_\alpha$ is an open nbhd of the point $\omega_1$ that is disjoint from $C$, so $\omega_1\notin\operatorname{cl}C$.

Your understanding in your second question is correct, though $\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ is a better analogue. Just as $\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ is the [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of $\Bbb N$, this space $X$ is the *one-point Lindelöfization* of a discrete space of cardinality $\omega_1$.

Comment: $C\subset \omega_1 \implies \sup C\lt \omega_1$ if $C$ is countable. What do we mean by $\sup C\ ?$ $\bigcup_{A\in C}A\ ?$

Comment: @user118494: $\omega_1$ has a natural order; $\sup C$ is the least upper bound of $C$ in that order. Yes, $\sup C=\bigcup C=\bigcup_{\alpha\in C}\alpha$.